# Add ng-option-selected dynamically to ng-select items

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the following code in Angular:

```
<ng-select
      placeholder="Type *"
      formControlName="types"
      [multiple]="true"
      [closeOnSelect]="false"
      [items]="availableTypes"
      bindValue="name"
      bindLabel="name"
      [selectableGroup]="true"
      [selectableGroupAsModel]="false"
    >
      <ng-template ng-header-tmp>
        <div class="select-all-option" (click)="onSelectAllOption()">
          Select All
        </div>
      </ng-template>
    </ng-select>
```

How do I make it so that when I select 'select all', the ng-option-selected class is dynamically added to all items (to show that all items are selected with a checkmark), and prevent other items from being selected until 'select all' is deselected?

this is my onSelectAllOption() method:

```
  onSelectAllOption() {
    this.selectAllTypes = !this.selectAllTypes
    this.filterForm.get('types').setValue(['All options selected'])
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, `<ng-select>` can work with Reactive Form. Thus, I don't see any reason that need to programmatically add the "ng-option-selected" class to all items.

Pre-requisites:

The `types` form control should be with value as an array.

```
onSelectAllOption() {
  this.filterForm.get('types').setValue(this.availableTypes.map((x) => x.name));
}
```

And make sure that the form control name referred should be correct, based on the HTML, your form control name is "types" but not "resourceTypes".

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t8ct5v?file=data.service.ts)

Comment: You're right, I edited the description accordingly. Btw the demo doesn't work

Comment: Apologize for that, maybe some issue in StackBlitz project. Will open it once with the PC.